# Change the type of event (keyup) to (keyup.enter) by script jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datatables

I need to create a jQuery script to ignore the execution of the keyup or keypress event listener function and execute it if only  I press the Enter key on the keyboard.

I am using a component of jquery, so I can not change the html code of the input.

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" id="search" class="search" (keyup)="searchDataTable($event)">
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).on("keypress", "input", function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode != 13) { 
        console.log('it is not enter keyCode ')
        //stop the execution of methode affected by event
    } 
});
```

I am looking for the javascript method that disables the listener.  **I want to:**

A. **execute the function, `searchDataTable($event)`**, **only if I press "enter".**

-OR-

B. **change the type of event (keyup) to (keyup.enter) by an other script jquery.**

Comment: Have you tried canceling the keypress event if it is not the enter key?

Comment: Doesn't make sense. If there is no listener how would you know if `enter` is pressed? What's wrong with checking the keyCode in `searchDataTable()`?

Comment: I wonder why you're using jQuery with Angular in the first place?

Comment: I agree with charlietfl.  It would make more sense to check the keycode in the searchDataTable method, rather than having two event listeners and try to have one prevent the other

Comment: Not clear enough. If you want to remove the keyup event listener use `$(document).off("keypress", "input");` but this won't fire again until you add the event listener again.

Comment: already I do not have the hand to change the event directly on html code that's why I want to create a script to: either execute the other function (in this exemple searchDataTable() ) or stop it

Comment: is there a reason you can Jquery scripts but not change the html can't you change the html ?

Comment: You can make changes to `searchDataTable($event)` function right?

Comment: no i can not make any changes on the searchDataTable () function. I used angular-datatables in an angular application with the DataTableDirective directive.
so it's a jquery component, we can not change the html code,only with DOM I think.

Comment: @SiddAjmera, It is not a wonder if you read the question and look at the tags ...And know what they all are about.

Comment: the real problem is not  the example at the top, I put this html example <input  > only to see an example similar to that of angular-datatables

Comment: why not simple (keyup.enter)="dosomething()" ?